# How to linearize an implication?

Tags: linear-algebra, operations-research, linearization, implication

Could someone help me linearize this implication?

Being x and y integer variables, the implication is the following

```
x >= 1 --> y = 0
y >= 1 --> x = 0
```

I would really appreciate some help.

Comment: Welcome to the site. This appears to be a pure math or cs question, both of which have their respective StackExchange sites. You might find better help there. StackOverflow is for programming questions.

Comment: @Calculuswhiz Modeling a problem to solve it with a MIP solver would seem to be a legitimate SO topic, wouldn't it?

Comment: There is also a dedicated operations research SE at https://or.stackexchange.com/ which would be a good match for this question.

Comment: @ChristopherHamkins If it's programming and code, absolutely. But those details would have to be edited in by the OP. Until then, I think it would be better to post this question on those other SE sites.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

Introduce a parameter t.

```
y = Max(1 - t, 0)
x = Min(t, 0)
```

and then linearize the Max and Min as described in https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/711/how-to-formulate-linearize-a-maximum-function-in-a-constraint

Answer (score 0):

Is there a way that both are zero? Because this seems like the usual complementarity constraints used into Battery optimization or Power Systems optimization and usual approach for this, for `x` and `y` being `binary` `Vars`:

```
x + y <= 1
```

Or the equality constraining:

```
x + y == 1
```